# Python - writing print

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn Python and going through some exercises, it’s all going good and I’ve learned some new stuff.

But I came across this code over the internet and it wants me to write out what the new Max and Min is supposed to become also B will be after the run.

I have tried to look for the correct answer but no one has printed it. I’ve tried to run it in my IDE but actually I never get an output. I’ve also tried writing “print(b)” but I get no result.

```
min = 5
max = 10
b = 0
a = -2

if a < min:
  min = a
elif a > max:
  max = a
else:
  b += 1
```

What I’ve thought the answer should be is Min will be -2 since a is declared as -2 and the first statement “if a < min:” says if -2 is less than 5, 5 will become -2.

Other statement “`a > max:`” asks if -2 is higher than 10, 10 will be –2 but since -2 is not higher we go to the else which says that we should plus 1 to 0 and that will give b = 1. So my answer is min = -2 , max = 10 , and b = 1.

Is my answer correct and if not what have I done wrong? Also, is there any way I can run it in python and get the answer through `print(b, max, min)` I’ve tried that but it’s not working.

Comment: add `print(a, b)` at the end of the program (with no indent)

Comment: You you're asking such questions, provide examples with your bad code as well, this will allow people trying to answer your question understand what you're doing wrong.

Comment: "I’ve tried that but it’s not working." What do you mean it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the second condition should be `if` not `elif`. An `if-elif-else` block exits as soon as any of them satisfies the condition. So, as in your code the first condition `if a < min` is `True`, the next conditions are not going to be checked.

```
min = 5
max = 10
b = 0
a = -2
if a < min:
  min = a
if a > max:
  max = a
else:            <-- this is executed only if: `a > max`: is `False`
  b += 1
print b, max, min
#1 10 -2
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, using that print showed me the answer and I could confirm what I thought was the answer.